# How can you convert milliseconds in a format with hours, minutes and seconds in Python? (over 24 hours)

Tags: python-3.x, time, data-conversion

i am having trouble converting milliseconds exerting 24 hours in python. for example, if my input is ms_to_hours(86400000) my result is '0:0:0', i don't want to include days in my calculation.
here is my code

```
def ms_to_hours(millis):
    millis = int(millis)
    seconds = (millis / 1000) % 60
    seconds = int(seconds)
    minutes = (millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60
    minutes = int(minutes)
    hours = (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24

    return("%d:%d:%d" % (hours, minutes, seconds))
```

I need help fixing this to display any milliseconds to (hours, minutes, seconds) even if input exudes 24 hours

Comment: So is your problem that your function returns 0:0:0 rather than 24:0:0 when given 86400000 as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

```
def ms_to_hours(millis):
    seconds, milliseconds = divmod(millis, 1000)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return ("%d:%d:%d" % (hours, minutes, seconds))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(ms_to_hours(88000000))
```

Output:

```
24:26:40
```